# How to use React within a NodeJs aws lambda function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless

I'm working on generating PDF files within an nodejs AWS lambda function. I've been using handlebars, but the html lacks flexibility, so I wanted to modularize the pdf components using React and am looking for assistance with implementation. is it possible?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/server-components

Comment: @CesarePolonara does this have any implementation for reactjs

Comment: react server components are still in alpha, they will be released soon.